# Generics query regarding typecast,static and instanceof

Tags: java, generics

1)I wonder why generic methods and classes don't take super keyword with them although extends is accepted?

2)Due to type erasure we can't use instance of operator with generics but then why is typecasting allowed?

eg:

```
 if (objecta instanceof Object){} //doesn't work  
 Collection collection = new ArrayList();   
 Collection<Integer> d1 = (Collection<Integer>)collection; //works fine.
```

As per my understanding it should not because we are trying to cast it to Collection and there is nothing as Collection at runtime.

3)I have read that static variables can't be a member of generics classes but I am not very clear why. Why the following behaviour is shown then?

```
 public class NoGenericss  
 { static List<Integer> list; //WORKS FINE  
 static List<T> list1; //COMPILATION ERROR
```

```
 public class Genericss<T>  

 { static List<Integer> list; //WORKS FINE   
 static List<T> list1; //COMPILATION ERROR  
 static void meth(T t){} //COMPILATION ERROR  
 static <S> void meth(S t){} //WORKS FINE
```

Why is there such a variable behaviour shown?

Comment: Your template parameters seem to be missing.

Comment: I believe something's missing in your code snippets. I don't see any generic type declarations. Did you careless copypaste your question from some other forum/website which swallowed generic type declarations as if it's HTML or something?

Comment: There were some formatting issues which I corrected.

Comment: please help if possible as generics seems so confusing

Answer (score 1):

For some reference for Java generics see the [Sun tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

### 2)

The `instanceof` operator is dynamic, meaning it checks type of an object during the runtime. Because of *type erasure*, the generic type of an object (such as a collection) is not available at runtime (a `List<Integer>`, `List<String`>, `List<URI>` become all just `List`s of some objects).

However, a cast is static. The type parameters of your variables are checked by the Java compiler. If you do this:

```
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List<String> strings = (List<String>) ints;
```

... the compiler displays an unchecked warning, because this operation is possible, but not safe. Because now when you do:

```
String s = ints.get(0);
```

You get a `ClassCastException` at runtime, because the VM will try to cast an `Integer` to a `String`.

This happens because the compiler compiles the above source code with generics into an equivalent of the following code. The type erasure is implemented in such a way, so that all the generic parameters go away, making all collections only collections of `Object`s and therefore, casts are inserted in the code wherever necessary.

```
List ints = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List strings = ints;
String s = (String) ints.get(0);
```

---

### 3)

The `<T>` type parameter is visible only to member fields and member methods. Each instance of a generic class can have a different `T`, for example if you have a class:

```
class List<T> { // this is not java.util.List, just some custom class
    public List<T> subList(int start, int end) { ... }
    ...
}
```

... then you can do:

```
List<String> strings = ...
List<String> stringsSub = strings.subList(1, 2);
```

... but also:

```
List<Integer> ints = ...
List<Integer> intsSub = ints.subList(1, 2);
```

As you can see, the first instance has the `T` set to `String`, the second to `Integer`. So the member method `subList` always returns a `List` of the same `T`.

Now, suppose you added a static field:

```
class List<T> {
    public static List<T> CONSTANT_LIST = ...
    ...
}
```

... what would the `T` be in the case of the `CONSTANT_LIST`? `String`, `Integer`, something else? Well, it's impossible to define, because statics exist independently of any of the class instances. That's why the `T` is invisible to them.

On the other hand, there is no problem to add a static with a concrete generic type:

```
class List<T> {
    public static List<Integer> CONSTANT_LIST = new List(1, 2, 3);
    ...
}
```

Comment: But then why : static <S> void meth(S t){} //WORKS FINE (last part of the question) takes generics  and also for a non generics class :  
 static List<T> list1 ....give compilation error

Comment: Because the `<S>` is a local type parameter that is exists only in the scope of the `meth` method that declared it. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html

Comment: Then if the class is non-generic and we use... static List<T> list1;..it gives error???coz then like the method discussed above this reference list1 is also not in method scope

Comment: The type parameter local to the given static method has to be declared before the return type, i.e. `static <S> List<S> getList();`. If you omit it: `static List<S>  getList();` then it won't compile.